# Deploying an application to Heroku and getting "no such file to load -- will_paginate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am running a Ruby 1.8.6, Rails 1.2 application on Heroku. I am using the [Aspen stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/aspen). When I attempt to deploy, the app crashes.

Here is what I have in the log

```
2012-03-13T08:43:44-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started  
2012-03-13T15:43:49+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by sunny.lanke@gmail.com  
2012-03-13T15:43:49+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5c774a1 by sunny.lanke@gmail.com  
2012-03-13T15:43:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting  
2012-03-13T08:43:50-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished  
2012-03-13T15:43:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 14350 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- will_paginate (MissingSourceFile)  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/../../activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'  

3:55+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config/../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/../../activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:343:in `new_constants_in'  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/../vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/../../activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:73  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems /custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.0.1/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:31:in `load_application'  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 12 levels...  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'  
2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1  
2012-03-13T15:43:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1  
2012-03-13T15:43:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed  
2012-03-13T15:43:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created  
2012-03-13T15:43:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting  
2012-03-13T15:43:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 54230 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`  `
```

EDIT: As per the suggestion, I have asked Heroku support to install the gem will_paginate. I will keep you guys posted about the result.

Comment: Application crashes. Not sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Could you paste your database.yml and Gemfile please?

Comment: my guess is it has something to do with this 2012-03-13T15:43:55+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- will_paginate (MissingSourceFile)

Comment: Also, are you using Ruby 1.8 I'm not sure if heroku still supports that... I could be wrong.

Comment: I am using heroku aspen which provides 1.8.6. database.yml is configured to work locally and its working fine locally. I understand it needs to be configured for heroku. But is that the real problem here ? Is there any way to push the local database to heroku ?

Comment: heroku rake db:migrate will install the database. As for your gem dependency you need to run bundle install locally then git heroku push master.

Comment: @Andre, really appreciate your help on this. Bundle is available in 1.8.6 ?

Comment: You should be able to to run gem install bundle --no-rdoc --no-ri, however ruby 1.8.7 is the minimum version accepted https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/commit/fd90347b9e86f271f1495bc5bb0b98c7ac566529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `will_paginate` gem.

If `will_paginate` even supports 1.8.6 you need to add it your `.gems` manifest.  If you're using Bundler, add it to your Gemfile and bundle before deploying.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gems

Comment: Thanks Neil, but heroku aspen doesnt support bundler. Is there any other way to install that gem on heroku ?

Comment: As @Neil says, you should use the `.gems` manifest, as indicated here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gemmanifest I would strongly recommend upgrading to at least 1.8.7 and preferably 1.9.2. Without bundler and using 1.8.6 and god knows which rails version, I am afraid you will find yourself in gem-hell, unless you vendorised your gems (which obviously you haven't).

Comment: @nathanvda Upgrading to 1.8.7 is not an option. rail version is 1.2.0
Its an old app that I have taken over to manage.

Comment: @sunny31: I can understand it is not an option for you. Time constraints or skill: upgrading can seem insurmountable. Personally I would consider it a must. You will only get into more trouble if you keep working on a Rails 1.2 system. Maybe for now you only needed to do a small change, but applications live. There will be a next change, and another: it will only get harder. Hope your boss/client can give you the time. You have my sympathy.